# Is it safe to recycle unshredded credit card receipts?

Tags: credit-card, identity, identity-management

Is it safe to recycle unshredded paper credit card receipts?  Can identity theft be helped by data disclosed on most vendor's receipts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most credit card receipts will contain your name and the last 4 digits of your card number.

I can think of several companies that either currently verify by last 4 digits or have *in the past* verified by last 4 digits. These are companies such as Apple, Godaddy, Paypal, etc...

So while the chances are low, it's still possible that someone *could* perform some degree of identity theft with this information.

Comment: There's [this famous case](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/), where the last four was part of the attack used to erase somebody's digital possessions.

Comment: When I worked at an Apple call centre, there was a similar case that was quoted when we were being trained for handling Apple IDs. That's primarily why I happen to take these precautions myself.